# How to ignore comma in values while reading csv files in R?

Tags: r, csv, tidyverse

I'm reading csv files in R from a folder which has bunch of csv files. I only need to read selected files where the filename contains a particular string ("Redundant"). In some of the desired files, one of the column ("ROLE") values contain comma. I need to ignore these commas. how do I do it?

For eg: some desired files have values like:

```
User,ROLE,Rule ID<br/>
amit,[oi.freetier.developer, gse.automationengineer],R12345
```

When I execute the below code:

```
files <- list.files(pattern='.*REDUNDANT(.*).csv$')

tbl <- sapply(files, read_csv, col_types = cols(.default = "c"), quote = "[]", simplify=FALSE) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "id") %>% select(id, `User Login`, `Rule ID`) %>% distinct()
```

I get the result like:

> ```
>    id                               `User` `Rule`              
>    <chr>                            <chr>        <chr>                  
>  1 Users.csv_REDUNDANT_amit.csv   amit       gse.automationengineer]
> ```

Comment: From your second sample line, it looks like you want comma to both act as a delimiter _and_ to also sometimes not act that way, but as plain text instead.  There is no easy solution for this, and in general you would have to write a parser.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Any leads?

Comment: `readr::read_csv` should be able to parse this, if the comma values are inside double quotes, which they should be, if the csv is formatted correclty.

Comment: Read as is then `paste` the 2nd and 3rd columns?

Comment: Thanks Julian but unfortunately the comma values are in not in double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can read in the files first as raw text so that you can replace the brackets with quotes, then read it as a csv:

```
tbl <- sapply(files, function(f) {
           gsub('\\[|\\]', '"', readLines(f)) %>%
               read.csv(text = ., check.names = FALSE)
       }) %>% 
       bind_rows(.id = "id") %>%
       select(id, User, `Rule ID`) %>%
       distinct()
```

Comment: Two notes: 1) you must set `check.names = FALSE` in `read.csv`; 2) the first column is just `User`, there is no `Login`. With those corrections your code works. And, `gsub('\\\[|\\\]', '"', readLines(f))` is simpler.

Comment: Thanks Braun and Rui. 
@RuiBarradas unfortunately I'm unable to put together your suggestions in the code. Would you be able ot help?

Comment: @RuiBarradas sorry but the code doesnt work for me. :(

Comment: the error I get is : " Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 must have names"